# cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: method toList()

Tags: java, collectors

I am  using java 11, using sts IDE, I compile and run the springboot application fine from the IDE, but when I compile it from command line using mvn

```
 mvn clean verify
```

I got this error

```
cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   method toList()
```

the code snippet is

```
......
......
return addressRepository.getAddressesBySystemUserId(systemUserId).stream().map(e -> {
            AddressDto dto = null;
            dto = AddressMapper.mapAddressToAddressDto(e);
            return dto;
        }).toList();

......
```

snippet of the pom file

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead

Comment: `Stream.toList()` is introduced in Java 16. So you don't have it in Java 11

Comment: But why the above code is working well while compiling/running the app using STS IDE, i already mentioned in the pom file file to use jdk 11, it seems that the STS IDE uses different version (not jdk 11 which i mentioned in the pom)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `.collect()` in order to collect list from stream in Java 11. In your case :

```java
return addressRepository.getAddressesBySystemUserId(systemUserId).stream().map(e -> {
            AddressDto dto = null;
            dto = AddressMapper.mapAddressToAddressDto(e);
            return dto;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to point out that you must use `.collect()` instead of `.toList()`

Comment: But why the above code is working well while compiling/running the app using STS IDE, i already mentioned in the pom file file to use jdk 11, it seems that the STS IDE uses different version (not jdk 11 which i mentioned in the pom)

Comment: What is the version at Java Build Path?

Comment: I have edited the post by adding the snippet of the pom file where i have mentioned that the compiler source and target are 11.

Comment: IDE's jdk version and your build tool's java version are different things. I presume your IDE's selected SDK is not 11. Please check it out.